# BigQuery Cloud Monitoring API - 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In Python I am writing query results (show how many queries are being run within a project) into a table ,which upon insertion will take the values entered and sends it to Stackdriver as a custom time series metric. Upon timeseries creation it returns an error saying `google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Metrics cannot be written to bigquery_project. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource for a list of writable resource types.: timeSeries[0].`
 The resource type I am using is `bigquery_project` but I do not believe that is the cause of my errors. I think that there is too many values at one  point per request (ex.the query response returns  20 queries at 12 :00) which causes  the error but if that is the cause how do I delay the time for each query response.

Here is some code :

```
def get_time_series(result):
    series = monitoring_v3.types.TimeSeries()
    series.metric.type = 'custom.googleapis.com/Blah/Blah_blah_blah'
    series.resource.type = 'bigquery_project'
    series.resource.labels['project_id'] = "project-name"
    series.resource.labels['region'] = 'us-central1'

    point = series.points.add()
    point.interval.end_time.seconds = int(time.time())
    try:
        point.value.int64_value = result
    except TypeError as type_err:
        print(f"Something went wrong  ..")
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        point.value.int64_value = int(
            (now - now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds() * 1000)
    return series

def query_stackoverflow():
    client_bq = bigquery.Client(project="project-name")
    client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
    query_job = client_bq.query("""
    SELECT
    job_id,
    creation_time,
    query,
    total_bytes_processed
    FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
    WHERE project_id ='project-name'
    AND creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC
    LIMIT 100""")

    results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
    rows = list(results)
    response =[]
    for row in rows:
        if row.total_bytes_processed is not None:
            cost_dollars = (row.total_bytes_processed / 1024 ** 4) * 5
            response.append(f"Creation_Time :{row.creation_time} | Estimated_Cost : {cost_dollars}".format(row.creation_time, cost_dollars))
        else:
            cost_dollars = (row.total_bytes_processed / 1024 ** 4) * 5
            response.append(f"Creation_Time :{row.creation_time} | Estimated_Cost : {cost_dollars}".format(row.creation_time, cost_dollars))
    # print(response)
    timeseries = []
    for x in range(0, len(list(response))):
        timeseries.append(get_time_series(response))
        print(timeseries)
        client.create_time_series("projects/project-name", timeseries)
        print("Blah metrics are successfully sent")
        print("FINISHED")
```

StackTrace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 690, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 592, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Metrics cannot be written to bigquery_project. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource for a list of writable resource types.: timeSeries[0]"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1585841627.232000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.10.138:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Metrics cannot be written to bigquery_project. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource for a list of writable resource types.: timeSeries[0]","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MalCode/PycharmProjects/Vulnerabilities/test.py", line 83, in <module>
    query_stackoverflow()
  File "C:/Users/MalCode/PycharmProjects/Vulnerabilities/test.py", line 76, in query_stackoverflow
    client.create_time_series("projects/project-name", timeseries)
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\monitoring_v3\gapic\metric_service_client.py", line 1039, in create_time_series
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MalCode\PycharmProjects\Vulnerabilities\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Metrics cannot be written to bigquery_project. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource for a list of writable resource types.: timeSeries[0]
```

Comment: If this error comes out of running your Python code, try also sharing your Python code.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I added some python code

Comment: Now the stack trace please? What line throws that error?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I updated once more and if you do not want to read the entire stack trace the error occurs ```line 76 client.create_time_series("projects/project-name", timeseries)```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your error message, in the documentation related to the [creation of custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitored_resources_for_custom_metrics), there is a list of the possible Monitored resource types available for its creation. However, the resource type: 'bigquery_project' is not found within them.

Instead, you can use the resource types: 'global', 'generic_node' and 'generic_task' in case there is no suitable resource type, in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#global-v-generic) you can find the differences between them and choose the one that best suits your case.

Comment: Thank you for responding  I have tried  changing the resource type and it was effective to a certain extent , But it doesnt answer the  duplication error I was receiving. I guess would know of a way to stop duplication within a time series?

Comment: I replicated your code and I was able to see that the duplicated results in your list ```timeseries``` is due to the casting to integer applied to ```time.time()```, at the same time, due to the casting in this line ```now - now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds() * 1000```. I recommend you log the results of these operations before and after the casting to verify it.